# Accessing the enum index from string

Tags: c++, enums

I have declared an enum like:

```
enum Month
{
    Mon,
    Tue,
    Wed,
    Thu,
    Fri,
    Sat,
    Sun
};
```

Now given a string `"Mon"`, how do I get 0, which is the index of it in the enum?

Is there any simple way to do it?

I am trying to write a function like `nextDay(day, number)`, which takes `day= "Mon"` or `"Tue"` or ..., and a number, and returns the day after that number of days.

So, if `day = "Mon"` and `number = 2`, it should return `"Wed"`.

So, I choose to use an enum for this. But I am stuck at this point.

Comment: There is no way to automatically map strings to enums. You can use something like a map to create the mapping for you.

Comment: `int day = Mon; printf("Three days after Monday is day number %d\n", day + 3);` If you want to get strings you can use an array of strings and use the enumeration as index.

Comment: Libraries like [better-enums](http://aantron.github.io/better-enums/) might help.

Comment: By the way, a name like `Month` for a *weekday* enumeration is mighty confusing.

Comment: Note: It's a better habit if you use enum classes instead of classic enums.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::map` to map a set of values to other values, eg:

```cpp
enum Day {
    Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun
};

#define ENTRY(d) {#d, d}

const std::map<std::string, Day> days = {
    ENTRY(Mon),
    ENTRY(Tue),
    ENTRY(Wed),
    ENTRY(Thu),
    ENTRY(Fri),
    ENTRY(Sat),
    ENTRY(Sun)
};

Day nextDay(const std::string &day, int number) {
    return static_cast<Day>((static_cast<int>(days.at(day)) + number) % 7);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/9wpWfD)

Answer (score -1):

This is how you declare an enum and use it. This is in C++

```cpp
enum week { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday };  
int main()  
{  
    week day;  
    day = Friday; // day = 4
    cout << "Day: " << day+1<<endl; // will return 5   
}
```

Enums start numbering at 0, and increment by 1 each entry. For it.

```cpp
enum week { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday };
week day = (week)2 //will return have day as wednesday
```

I really don't know how to convert day to String. But my best bet would be on dictionary.

```cpp
#include<iostream.h>
using std::map
map<int, string> week = {1:"Mon",2:"Tue",.....,6:"Sun"};
 
int main()
{
   string day = week[2]; // day = "Wed";
   cout<<day<<endl; // will print "Wed"
}
```

Comment: Nothing in your example answers the OP's actual question of how to convert a string `"Mon"" to 0, etc.